# How can I get a parallel stream of Files.walk?

Tags: java, file, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I need to do some read-only processing on a all files in a folder recursively. I'm using `Files.walk` to get a stream of the files, but I noticed that the api specifies that `walk` only returns a regular stream, not a parallel stream.

How can I process all the files in a directory in parallel?

Comment: Maybe something like `Files.walk(...).parallel()`?

Comment: @Flown Hah... silly me. Didn't realize you can convert normal streams to parallel.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can transform any `Stream` into a parallel `Stream` by invoking `Stream::parallel`.

```
Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(startPath).parallel().forEach(...);
```

Comment: Note that `Files.walk` parallelizes poorly especially if your subtree has less than 1024 files. If you have much per-file processing and not so many files, it would be probably more efficient to `Files.walk(path).collect(toList()).parallelStream()`.

Comment: @TagirValeev Interesting. Do you have a link explaining why this is so?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg, JDK source code and benchmarks. It uses `Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize` internally which splitting strategy is to load chunks into arrays starting with 1024 elements. As size is unknown, Stream pipeline engine assumes that split produces even parts, but they are actually not (first split for <=1024 input dumps all the elements into prefix leaving no elements for the suffix). This results in very bad parallel performance.

Comment: Does not work, calling parallel on a stream from Files.walk does not makes it run in parallel. JDK 1.8

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. The Files.walk stream does not seem to work parallel. Ever afer transforming the stream into a parallel stream by invoking `parallel()` the processing was performed in one thread only.

The only solution was to transform collected the `Paths` in a list and create a parallel stream on this list as mentioned by Tagir Valeev.

Not working solution:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir")))
                    .parallel()
                    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                    ...
```

Working solution:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir")))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    .parallelStream()
                    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                    ...
```